# What front framework for my sailsjs application?

Tags: extjs, sails.js

I fell in love with sailsjs but I still search for a proper front web framework for my web "desktop oriented" application.
I don't target tablets and mobile devices but large screens, so I want to propose left menus, trees, grids, and all classical "desktop" controls.
A priori, Extjs seems to be the framework I want but I've got the impression that marry it with sailjs will be difficult.

Any experience feedbacks?

Comment: Why do you think it will be complicate to use ext and sails together ? There no reason it will be more complicate than another server side. All you have to do with sails is make web services in ExtJS format, not very complicated

Comment: ExtJS isn't hard to get working with sails, but it's deficient in a lot of other ways (from experience). Everyone is using react.js these days. You probably should too.

Comment: @jaumard some collegues of mine talked about the difficulties to get SenchaCmd work correctly with sailsjs, especially when it comes to the grunt task dedicated to watch every modification in the assets project, performance issues, etc

Comment: @TravisWebb wow. React seems awesome! I'm just wondering how difficult it will be to get grids, trees, etc etc with it, but all I read about it for now please me.

Comment: https://github.com/tjwebb/react-kendo